# How to mock HttpClient class to return different responses

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

How can I make Mockito return different HttpEntity values in response to different URIs?

The test is going to make multiple HTTP requests (all of them are POST requests) with the mockHttpClient.

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = EntityBuilder.create().setText(response).build();
PowerMockito.when(response, "getEntity").thenReturn(httpEntity);
```

And the test itself is designed this way:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = mockHttpClient(200, HTTP_ENTITY);
runTest();
Mockito.verify(client, Mockito.times(2)).execute(Mockito.any());
```

For the above test to return different HTTP entities, I tried the following:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    Mockito.when(client.execute(new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/a"))).thenReturn(resp1);
    Mockito.when(client.execute(new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/a/b"))).thenReturn(resp2);
```

But I'm unable to build different http entities and get in response based on the URIs in the request.

Comment: I came across this question when I was trying to figure out how to mock the response of the send / sendAsync method on HttpClient. For an answer to that, see stackoverflow.com/a/76778792/925913.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you mle.
Your response helped me understand how to better structure a test. But in this case I'm trying to modify one without any restructuring.

I thought I ll post my answer here just in case someone else is looking for one.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<CloseableHttpResponse>() {
  @Override
  public CloseableHttpResponse answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);

    // No change to status code based on endpoints
    Mockito.when(status.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(withResponseCode);
    Mockito.when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(status);

    HttpEntity entity = Mockito.mock(HttpEntity.class);
    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
    String endpoint = ((HttpPost) args[0]).getURI().getPath();
    if (endpoint.contains("/a/b")) {
      entity = EntityBuilder.create().setText("something").build();
      Mockito.when(httpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(entity);
    } else {
      entity = EntityBuilder.create().setText("something else").build();
      Mockito.when(httpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(entity);
    }
    return httpResponse;
  }
}).when(client).execute(Mockito.any(HttpUriRequest.class));
```

The integration test does is not testing the rest client itself and I don't need knobs and multiple mock clients for different responses. And the above helps me in returning different responses based on the endpoint that is receiving requests.

Answer (score 4):

First things first, there is no need for `Powermock` in this case. You do not need to mock static methods, constructors or anything else nasty.

I've prepared a little example test, which works out of the box for me here with `Mockito 2.23.4`, and you can see that the assertion **`isSameAs`** *("Verifies that the actual value is the same as the given one, ie using == comparison.")* really checks if a certain `POST` call matches the previously mocked response:

```
public class CloseableHttpClientTest {
    private final CloseableHttpClient client = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);

    @Test
    public void mockClient() throws IOException {
        // given
        CloseableHttpResponse resp1 = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
        CloseableHttpResponse resp2 = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
        HttpPost post1 = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/a");
        HttpPost post2 = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/a/b");
        when(client.execute(post1)).thenReturn(resp1);
        when(client.execute(post2)).thenReturn(resp2);

        // when
        CloseableHttpResponse returnedResp1 = client.execute(post1);
        CloseableHttpResponse returnedResp2 = client.execute(post2);

        // then
        assertThat(returnedResp1).isSameAs(resp1);
        assertThat(returnedResp2).isSameAs(resp2);
        verify(client).execute(post1);
        verify(client).execute(post2);
    }
}
```